# Can an object be undefined but yet have a defined property? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I have a slightly embarrassing question relating to a simple Javascript function I have come across:

```
Passport.prototype.use = function(name, strategy) {
  if (!strategy) {
    strategy = name;
    name = strategy.name;
  }
  if (!name) throw new Error('authentication strategies must have a name');

  this._strategies[name] = strategy;
  return this;
};
```

I believe the purpose of this function is to give a strategy a `name`, overriding a default name it may have.

I believe the first part of the function is essentially assigning `strategy.name` to `name`, given the case that strategy is undefined  `if(!strategy){}`. This does not feel intuitive to me. How can `strategy.name` be defined if this code is only ran if `strategy` is not defined? Ie. can an undefined object have a defined property—or am I looking at this incorrectly?

As a side note—I've been scouring the web trying to figure out the use of the `_` throughout javascript. I know the underscore.js library is pretty popular, but that library hasn't been loaded so this underscore must signify something else.

Anyways, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Because `strategy = name` assigns the first argument to `strategy`

Comment: It’s argument overloading. `strategy` is originally just the name for the second argument; if the second argument isn’t passed (is `undefined`), it assumes that the strategy was really passed as the first argument (originally called `name`), so it reassigns `strategy` the value of the first argument instead and takes `name` out of the strategy’s `name` property, akin to calling the function as `passport.use(strategy.name, strategy)`.

Comment: Imagine calling it like this ~ `passport.use({name: 'foo'})`. Now `strategy` will be `{name: 'foo'}` and `name` will be `'foo'`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Not sure why I was downvoted. I feel like this is a totally legitimate question.

Comment: On the issue of the `_`, it's a common naming convention to prefix "private" variables with an underscore. They aren't really private, just not intended for public use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For organization sake's, let's formalize the comments section (btw, why do so many people answer via comments nowadays?)

#### Argument overloading

This is (unfortunately) quite common in Javascript. It's a way to provide *two interfaces* with the same function. In my opinion, this generally leads to confusion.

Nonetheless, in this case, the author wants to offer two signatures:

`Prototype.use(strategy: Object)`

and

`Prototype.use(name: String, strategy: String)`

Allowing a caller to either:

`Passport.use("name", "strategy");`

or

`Passport.use({ "name": "name" });`

Therefore, if the second argument is falsy (`if (!strategy)`) then use the first argument instead (`strategy = name;`).

#### """Private""" variables

Javascript lacks "private" variables (except for closures) so using an underscore to prefix your `_property` indicates that it should not be accessed by external code, i.e. "use at your own peril, may break".